# Finding $x$ from inequality: $\left | \frac{3^n + 2}{3^n + 1} - 1 \right | \le \frac{1}{28}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

> Find $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying this inequality:
>
> $$\left | \frac{3^n + 2}{3^n + 1} - 1 \right | \le \frac{1}{28}.$$

I tried something, but I don't think it's correct.

$$-\frac{1}{28} \le \frac{3^n + 2}{3^n + 1} - 1 \le \frac{1}{28}$$

I arrived at:

$$-3^n - 1 \le 28 \le 3^n + 1.$$

I don't know if it's ok or not.

Comment: It might help you to combine $${3^n+2\over3^n+1}-1$$ into a single fraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$\left|\;\frac{3^n+2}{3^n+1}-1\;\right|=\frac1{3^n+1}\le\frac1{28}\iff\ldots$$

Note that $\,3^n+1>0\;,\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;$

Comment: I have nothing more that you noted ;) Just to make a machinery approach. That's it. Of course the OP didn't want it:)

Comment: i arrived here : -1/28<=1/(3^n+1)<=1/28 and i don't know what else to do.I tried to reduce to a common denominator and i got this:    −3n−1≤28≤3n+1 Can you tell me the next step?

Comment: @marinaaaa, you don't need all that: the expression inside the absolute value is always positive! You can erase the absolute value and work without it, as shown above...

Answer (score 0):

the answer is [3, infinity)    because n is greater than or = 3